# How to _.debounce() based on param value?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

What is an elegant way to check a param value within _.debounce()?

```
var renderPage = _.debounce(function(pageNo){
     // render code for page=pageNo immediately, then
     // debounce repeated calls for the SAME pageNo
     // but a DIFFERENT pageNo would have a different debounce setTimeout()
}, 1000, true)

renderPage(1);  // render immediate
renderPage(1);  // debounced
renderPage(2);  // render immediate
renderPage(2);  // debounced
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good answers here, but another possibility is memoization.  Something like:

```
var renderPage = function (pageNo) {
    renderPage._pageNos = renderPage._pageNos || {};
    if (!(pageNo in renderPage._pageNos)) {
        renderPage._pageNos[pageNo] = _.debounce(function () {
            // Do renderPage() work here
        }, 1000, true);
    }
    renderPage._pageNos[pageNo]();
}
```

[JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/7Z7J9/).

Comment: I never 1) understood memoization, or 2) knew you could add properties to a function. but underscore has a _.memoize() function, and I ended up using that to store the _.debounce() function.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a possible solution? I went back to the underscore source. I think you need to keep track of the different setTimeout calls to get things done. Is there a more general way to keep the timers arg 'static' somewhere?

```
    _.debounceByArgs = function(func, wait, immediate, timers) {
        var timeout = timers || {};
        return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var id = JSON.stringify(args);
            var later = function() {
                timeout[id] = null;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout[id]);
            timeout[id] = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
var debouncer = function(func, timer){
    return _.debounce(func, timer, true);
}

var renderPage = function(num){


}

var renderPage1 = debouncer(renderPage, 1000);
var renderPage2 = debouncer(renderPage, 2000);
```

Ok how about something along the lines of:

```
var rp = function(num){
  //actual render page code here
}

var renderPage = function(num, timer){
    if(typeof(this[num]) === "undefined"){
        this[num] = _.debounce(rp, timer, true);
    }
    this[num](num);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid a new function for each page. the number of pages is indeterminate